# cannot understand python match case

Tags: python, match, case

why the two examples give 2 different results? if `str()` is equal to `''` the result should be the same.

```
    # example 1
    match 'ciao':
        case str():
            print('string')
        case _:
            print('default')
    
    # >>> string
    
    # example 2
    match 'ciao':
        case '':
            print('string')
        case _:
            print('default')
    
    # >>> default
    
    # but ...
    assert str() == ''
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR `case str():` contains a *class pattern* that only looks like a function call, but as a pattern it matches any string, not just the empty string.

---

`str()` in this case is *not* a function-call expression that evaluates to `''`. Rather, it is a *class pattern*, a syntactic construct that only exists inside `match` statements and has different semantics from the otherwise identical-looking expression. You can read more about [class patterns in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-patterns), but in short, `str()` matches *any* instance of `str`.

```
match 'ciao':
    case str():
        print('string')
    case _:
        print('default')
```

is equivalent to

```
if isinstance('ciao', str):
    print('string')
else:
    print('default')
```

Similary, `''` in your second `match` statement is not an expression that evaluates to the empty string (though the distinction is less meaningful and much, much less obvious), but a [literal pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#literal-patterns) that matches the empty string.

```
match 'ciao':
    case '':
        print('string')
    case _:
        print('default')
```

is equivalent to

```
if 'ciao' == '':
    print('string')
else:
    print('default')
```

Part of the power of a `match` statement is that each case can use a different *kind* of pattern (indeed, in both your examples `_` is a third kind, a [wildcard pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#wildcard-patterns)), so it's not straightforward to convert a `match` statement to an equivalent `if` statement in general.

Comment: In most simplest way and most excellent answer. Thanks @chepner for knowledge added.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid the  edited answer is not as simple anymore. Maybe it needs a TL;DR at the top...

Comment: This [link](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#matching-builtin-classes) will also useful for the future readers.